# Finding SSL cert location by connecting to the port

Tags: openssl, ssl, certificates

I know we can retrieve the SSL cert with

```
openssl s_client -connect host:port
```

command. Is there any way to find out the file system location of the cert that was used by the process handling the SSL traffic? Am I being very unreasonable?

Comment: I doubt that's possible: leaking this information could be a security risk.

Comment: It would depend on the service itself being awfully badly designed.  If you do encounter one, you should file a major bug report.

Comment: Could it be that you meant the location of the CA certificates?

Comment: @phk: no, the server SSL cert.

Comment: Then this certainly isn't a UNIX/Linux specific question but a question of the protocol design and no the protocol does not leak this information.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because what the OP asked for is simply not intended by design, nor is it really related to U&L.

Comment: @countermode The fact that it's impossible doesn't invalidate the question or make it off-topic. “It's impossible” (with explanation) is the proper answer.

Comment: I agree with @countermode.  This is a *valid* question.  Recently, I was building an SSL certs monitor and this question popped up automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't get that information. It's none of the TLS client's business. It's purely up to the server how and where it loads its certificate (and private key) from. It might not even come from a file on a filesystem but from, say, an HSM.

Comment: In some cases. including an IPS DLP or similar interceptor, the cert may be created on the fly and not ever stored anywhere.